# Как правильно кодировать значение cookie

Tags: http, cookie

Вопрос по теории HTTP

Читал [RFC6262](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6265.html) и не совсем понял как правильно кодировать значение cookie.
Есть скрипт который общается с сайтом и есть кука `cookiename` со значением: `a=1&b=c`, следовательно я должен послать в сторону сайта:

```
Cookie: cookiename=...
```

Как варианты:

- `a=1&b=c` т.е. оставить строку как есть (а перекодировать символы \x0-\x20, ';')
- `a%3D1%26b%3Dc`
- `"a=1&b=c"`

Что произойдет если нужно перекодировать значение `hello, world!`?

- `hello%20%2Cworld%21`
- `"hello, world!"`

Answer (score 1):

Можно перевести массив с параметрами в JSON.

Comment: Можно конечно, можно и urlencode, но интересует как должно быть по стандарту?
Вопрос не в том как должен вести мой сайт, а как мне эмулировать поведение броузера?